# ReportItems! RDLC Reports (MS Dynamics NAV)

Tags: report, rdlc, dynamics-nav

I wanted to put an if condition in RDLC Reports to check a textbox value before placing a value in it but i am not getting the result desired

My code as follows:

```
=iif(ReportItems!CustAddr611.Value<>"",Code.GetData(6,1),Code.GetData(54,1) & " " & Code.GetData(55,1))
```

But it gives me an error display `#Error` when i run the report in NAV.

Also how can i add multiple report items in the conditional statement. VS tells me this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       The Value expression for the textrun ‘CustAddr711.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ refers to more than one report item.  An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item.

Comment: As for the second part of the question I suppose you should use something like [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251663(v=vs.90).aspx) function to get exactly one record from recordset. By `CustAddr711.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]` you referring to all records which you can not do in header or footer.

Comment: yes we need to know In what part of the report are your trying to do this. Otherwise we can't help

Answer (score 0):

Often when referring directly to Report items you can get in a situation, where the ReportItem is out of scope, specifically if you move your elements around.

Your value might be out of scope or not set at all, I suggest that you try and put it in a variable in the Report Code.

```
Shared CustAddr611 as String

Public Function SetCustAddr611(Value as String) As String
CustAddr611 = Value
Return CustAddr611
End Function

Public Function GetCustAddr611 As String
Return CustAddr611
End Function
```

In your report items you use SetCustAddr611() when inserting it in the report and GetCustAddr611 in your iif